# Express 4 namespace param?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been working with Express 4 and I just tried to use a namespaced route, but I wanted the namespaced route to have a param.

For instance:

```
/:username/shows
/:username/shows/:showname/episodes
```

etc etc. So with this, I thought this would be a good fit for express namespacing.

```
Router = require("express").Router;
userRouter = Router();

userRouter.route("/shows").get(function(req,res){ ... });
app.use("/:param", userRouter);
```

This would get the page to load as expected at `/:username/shows`, however the `req.params`, where I'd normally expect to find a key called `username` was empty. Am I missing something? Where can I access these params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `:username` param is used by app, not in `userRouter`.
You can only access that from `app`, or you can curry `:username` param information to `userRouter` by using `app.params()` function

```
app.param('username', function(req, res, next, username) {
  req.username = req.params.username;
  next();
});

app.use('/:username', userRouter);

userRouter.get('/show', function(req, res, next){
  var username = req.username; // Here you can access;
  res.send("DONE");
});
```